# Layered Navigation issue on catalog search result page in magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2

can anyone please tell me why am I not getting layered navigation in catalog search result page in magento 2.4.5?

I tried various modules.
currently I don't have any module of Layered Navigation using magento default only.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.